# Reference each variable in a 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, sql-server

I have a script have accesses records in a column in a MSSQL db. I then loop through these to do stuff.  For example, the column ASXCode is passed to my `for` loop.

I’d like to be able to retrieve 2 columns from my table (2d array) and then access each variable ASXCode and Sector. 
How do I reference each variable like in my Example 2?

## Example 1

```
import csv
import os
import pymssql

conn = pymssql.connect(server='', user='', password='', database='')

ASXCodes = conn.cursor()
ASXCodes.execute('SELECT ASXCode FROM tbl_Company')

for ASXCode in ASXCodes:
  print(ASXCode)
conn.close()
```

## Example 2

```
ASXCodes = conn.cursor()
ASXCodes.execute('SELECT ASXCode, SECTOR FROM tbl_Company')

for ASXCode in ASXCodes:

  print(1st column)
  print(2nd column)

conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So now you have two elements to iterate over, so something like

```
for code, sector in ASXCodes:
    print(code)
    print(sector)
conn.close()
```

btw, you might want to use something like

```
cur.execute('SELECT ASXCode, SECTOR FROM tbl_Company')

for code, sector in cur:
  ....
```

as it might improve readability a great deal...